# How do I smoothly rotate the camera in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I am making a 2d unity game with C#. Right now, I am trying to make the camera rotate and I am using this code:

```
rotateX = Random.Range (0, 50);
Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3(0,0,rotateX);
```

But every time I try to run the game, it gives me an error.
Anybody have tips on how I can (smoothly) rotate the camera from side to side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get rid of errors by changing your code to this:

```
void Update () {
    float rotateX = Random.Range (0, 50);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,rotateX);
}
```

And attaching script component containing it to the camera. But then it is rotating randomly all the time.

I'm not sure, from the question, what kind rotation do you want. But you can use for example this

```
void Update () {
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 10.0f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

to rotate the camera smoothly. Just change to first parameter to the axis around what you want to rotate.

Comment: If you use the keyword "new" in the Update() isn't it slowly filling up the RAM?

Comment: I haven't coded any C# in years but I am quite sure that the garbage collector will take care of deleting old variables after they are replaced with a new one. I know that the ´new´ looks bad to anyone with, for example, C++ background.

Comment: Yes, C# has a garbage collector which will take care of deleting unused objects.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Camera.main. Write a class for your camera and then add it to the camera in the scene. Use transform.rotation like this:

```
void Update () 
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, z);
    transform.position = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, z);
}
```

see this for more info:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MouseOrbitImproved

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are missing the `new` initializer.

```
rotateX = Random.Range (0, 50);
Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,rotateX); //<--- put 'new' before 'Vector3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to place that code into your gameobject  add current camera which you want it to rotate.

```
public class swipebutton : MonoBehaviour
```

{
    public Camera cam;

```
void Update()
{

    cam.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 20.0f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}